# changing the value of a json pair jq

Tags: jquery, json, kubernetes

Here is my json input

```json
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "data": {
    "POSTGRES_PASSWORD": "cXVhbGltYXJiJi0xZDYK"
  },
  "kind": "Secret",
  "metadata": {
    "creationTimestamp": null,
    "labels": {
      "io.kompose.service": "POSTGRES_PASSWORD"
    },
    "name": "postgres-password"
  },
  "type": "Opaque"
}
```

I want the same json file in output but after changing `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` into `cXVhbGltYXJiJi0xZDY=` (only change the last character 'K' into `=`).
I tried some kind of work with `with_entries`

```bash
jq -r '.data|with_entries(.value == "cXVhbGltYXJiJi0xZDY=")
```

without any success.
This is a k8s secret and secret can be any other than `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`, so I'd like to make a global jq rule that could replace the last character of the base64 password with `=`.
The output should be

```json
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "data": {
    "ANY_PASSWORD": "any_password_base64="
  },
  "kind": "Secret",
  "metadata": {
    "creationTimestamp": null,
    "labels": {
      "io.kompose.service": "ANY_PASSWORD"
    },
    "name": "any-password"
  },
  "type": "Opaque"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the following `jq` command:

```bash
jq '.data |= with_entries(.value |= sub("K$"; "=")) | .metadata.labels."io.kompose.service" |= sub("POSTGRES_PASSWORD"; "ANY_PASSWORD") | .metadata.name |= sub("postgres-password"; "any-password")' input.json
```

This command does the following:

1. Uses `with_entries` to iterate over each key-value pair in the `.data` object.
2. Applies the `sub` function to replace the 'K' at the end of the value with '='.
3. Uses `sub` to replace the "POSTGRES_PASSWORD" label with "ANY_PASSWORD" in `.metadata.labels."io.kompose.service"`.
4. Uses `sub` to replace the "postgres-password" name with "any-password" in `.metadata.name`.

This should give you the desired output.

Comment: The exact goal was to remove any `\n` character into the base64 password, so here is what I finally did: `jq -r '.data|=with_entries(.value |=(@base64d|sub("\n";"")|@base64))'`